# Is there any way to step through more then one range of cells during the same For Each loop?

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently trying to create a loop that steps through 2 ranges of data. First range is b16-b35 next range is j16-j35. Currently I can only get 1 of the 2 loops to step through.

I started with a For While loop. Using i as a variable for 16-35. When I tried this method I couldnt get the msgbox to print the data. I moved to a For each loop. This gave me the ability to step through 1 cell but not the other.

```
If [D8] = 2 Then

    Dim r As Range
    Dim j As Range
    Dim jcell As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Set r = Range("B16:B35")
    Set j = Range("J16:J35")
    For Each cell In r
    For Each hcell In j
        If cell = "" Or cell = "N/A" Then GoTo ENDGAME

        MsgBox "pn is " & cell & " route is " & jcell

Next jcell

Next cell

ENDGAME:

End IF
```

Current method causes the loop to step through all of J for each r. I have tried combining the for each loops with an and statement and it bugs the code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like really you have one loop (process), it's just that your data feels to be in two different places. Let's loop through B16:B35, referencing the corresponding values in column J as we go:

```
Sub looper()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    If [D8] = 2 Then

        Set r = Range("B16:B35")

        For Each cell In r

            If cell = "" Or cell = "N/A" Then GoTo ENDGAME

            MsgBox "pn is " & cell & " route is " & cell(1, 9)

        Next cell

ENDGAME:

    End If

End Sub
```

So `cell` is the range object, starting with B16... you can reference a different cell by its *offset* from a range object... cell(1, 9) means take the `cell`, look at the same row (1), but the 9th column (count column B as "one", column C as two; column J is nine).

It's normally a good idea to declare variables at the top of the sub, that's why I moved the Dims. Not strictly necessary for this code to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter as the For loop, and use that to set a reference into each range

```
Dim r As Range
Dim j As Range
Dim jcell As Range
Dim rcell As Range
Dim i as Long
Set r = Range("B16:B35")
Set j = Range("J16:J35")
For i = 1 to r.Rows.Count
    Set rcell = r.Cells(i, 1)
    Set jcell = j.Cells(i, 1)
    MsgBox "pn is " & rcell.Address & " route is " & jcell.Address
Next i
```

Comment: This assumes r and j have same dimensions. So it is not clean as Union. I know op said that in his question though. So fair point.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure what you are trying to do, but the following should do perform what you would like to..

Btw, defining cell as a range etc. is not best practice. it is better to give it a name other than a function, etc name.

```
    with thisworkbook.sheets(1)
        if .range("B8").value = 2 then
            for i = 16 to 35
                if .range("B" & i).value = "" or .range("B" & i).value = "N/A" then
                    goto EndGame
                else
                    msgbox "pn is " & .range("B" & i).value & " route is " & .range("J" & i).value
                end if
            next i
        EndGame:
        end if
    end with
```

If you want to do 2 loops, first for B , than for J, you can do this. However, if one of the cells in one of the loops contains nothing or n/a -> function will stop. If you want to go to the next (i) ; iteration. you should put the:

```
EndGame:
```

just before:

```
next i
```

--

```
    dim First_Range_Done as boolean

    with thisworkbook.sheets(1)
        if .range("B8").value = 2 then

            for i = 16 to 35

                if First_Range_Done = false then
                    if .range("B" & i).value = "" or .range("B" & i).value = "N/A" then
                        goto EndGame
                    else
                        msgbox "pn is " & .range("B" & i).value & " route is " & .range("J" & i).value
                    end if
                end if

                if First_Range_Done = true
                    if .range("J" & i).value = "" or .range("J" & i).value = "N/A" then
                        goto EndGame
                    else
                        msgbox "pn is " & .range("B" & i).value & " route is " & .range("J" & i).value
                    end if

                    if i = 35 then exit sub
                end if

                if i = 35 then
                    First_Range_Done = true
                    i = 15
                end if

            next i

        EndGame:
        end if
    end with
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim u As Range
Dim res As String
Set r1 = Range("A1:B1")
Set r2 = Range("C3:D3")
Set u = Union(r1,r2)
res = ""
For Each cell In u
   res = res + cell.Value2
Next cell
MsgBox res
```

Assuming cells have following values:

```
-------------------
| Address | Value | 
-------------------
| A1      | a1    |
| B1      | b1    |
| C3      | c3    |
| D3      | d3    |
-------------------
```

You would get `a1b1c3d3` as result being displayed by `MsgBox`.

With this method you have the added bonus, you can combine ranges of different dimensions.

Comment: Someone gave this a minus. But it works. And it's the simplest, most foolproof way to code solution.